# How to change "Cancel" button text in modal sheet view in SwiftUI on watchOS 7?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I have 2 simple views:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingModalView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingModalView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Modal View")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingModalView) {
            ModalView()
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Modal View")
    }
}
```

When "Show Modal" button pressed, `ModalView` is show.

How to change text "Cancel" when `ModalView` is active to something else?

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This Cancel is actually a navigation bar item. You can replace it with own button using toolbar, like

[image: demo1]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingModalView = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingModalView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Modal View")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingModalView) {
            ModalView()
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                    Button("Close") { self.showingModalView = false }
                }
            })

        }
    }
}
```

also you can hide it at all (and make your custom approach to close, eg. with button in sheet view, etc.)

```
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showingModalView) {
        ModalView()
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I am able to replace the Cancel button with Close. But do you know why the Close Button does not respond, and the modal sheet does not dismiss? I find the behavour of modal sheets unpredictable and don't understand why sometimes they work and sometimes not.

Comment: I thought this was a SwiftUI bug since watchOS 7. Thanks a lot for this